# cosine has disappeared in the second order linear equation in ordinary differential equation(ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

$$  \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d t ^{2}   } = - \frac{  MH  }{  I  } \theta_{}  $$

$$  M,H,I ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{constants}  $$

My tries are as below.

$$  \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d t ^{2}   } + \frac{  MH  }{  I  }\theta_{} =0  $$

$$  \theta_{} ''+ \frac{  MH  }{  I  } \theta_{} =0 $$

$$  \lambda ^{2} + \frac{  MH  }{  I  } =0 $$

$$  \lambda ^{2}    = -\frac{  MH  }{  I  }  $$

$$  \therefore ~~  \lambda =\pm  \sqrt{ \frac{ - MH  }{ I   }  }  $$

$$ = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{  MH  }{ I   }  } i $$

$$ = 0\pm \sqrt{ \frac{  MH  }{ I   }  } i $$

$$  \alpha \rightarrow 0 $$

$$  \beta \rightarrow \sqrt{ \frac{  M H  }{I    }  }  $$

$$  \therefore ~~ \theta_{} = \left\{ C_{1}  \cos\left(\beta t\right) +C_{2} \sin\left(\beta t\right)  \right\}  \exp\left(\alpha t\right)   $$

$$ = \left\{ C_{1}  \cos\left(\beta t\right) +C_{2} \sin\left(\beta t\right)  \right\} \exp\left(0  \cdot t \right)  $$

$$ = \left\{ C_{1}  \cos\left(\beta t\right) +C_{2} \sin\left(\beta t\right)  \right\} $$

$$ = \left\{ C_{1}  \cos\left(\sqrt{ \frac{  M H  }{I    }  }  t\right) +C_{2} \sin\left(\sqrt{ \frac{  M H  }{I    }  }  t\right)  \right\} $$

However the book shows the below.

$$  \theta_{} = \theta_{0} \sin\left(\sqrt{ \frac{  M H  }{I    }  } t+ \gamma\right)  $$

$$  \theta_{0} ,\gamma ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{constants}  $$

Where I made mistake(s)?

Comment: You made no mistake. The book used a trig identity tu express the solution that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't make any mistake. There are two forms to write the solutions. One is $A\cos(w_0t)+B\sin(w_0t)$ and the other is $\cos(w_0t + \phi)$ or $\sin(w_0t + \psi)$ (they are the same). See [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/%7Ehaber/ph5B/sho09.pdf) (page $2$) for more details.